# Hibernate concurrency creating a duplicate record on saveOrUpdate

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, hibernate, concurrency

I'm trying to implement a counter with Java, Spring, Hibernate and Oracle SQL. Each record represents a count, by a given timestamp. Let's say each record is uniquely identified by the minute, and each record holds a count column. The service should expect to receive a ton of concurrent requests and my update a counter column for possibly the same record.

In my table, if the record does not exist, just insert the record in and set its count to 1. Otherwise, find the record by timestamp and increase its existing counter column by 1.

In order to ensure that we're maintain data consistency and integrity, I'm using pessimistic locking. For example, if 20 counts come in at the same time, and not necessarily by the same user, it's possible that we may override the record from a stale read of that record before updating. With locking, I'm ensuring that if 20 counts come in, the net effect on the database should represent the 20 count.

So locking is fine, but the problem is that if the record never did exist in the first place, and we have two or more concurrent requests coming in trying to update the not-yet-existant record, I've observed that the a duplicate record gets inserted because we cannot lock on a record that doesn't exist yet. How can we ensure that no duplicates get created in the table? Should it be controlled via Oracle? Or can I manage this via my app and Hibernate?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One was to avoid this sort of problem altogether would be to just generate the count at the time you actually query the data.  Oracle has an analytic function `ROW_NUMBER()` which can assign a row number to each record in the result set of a query.  As a rough example, consider the following query:

```
SELECT
    ts,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ts) rn
FROM yourTable
```

The count you want would be in the `rn` column, representing the number of records appearing since the first entry in the table.  Of course, you could further restrict the query.

This approach is robust to removing records, as the count would always start with 1.  One drawback is that row number functionality is not supported by Hibernate.  You would have to run this either as a native query or a stored proc.